# proving that $8x^3-6x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

When considering the impossibility of trisecting the 60 degree angle, one comes across the polynomial $f(x)=8x^3-6x-1$, which I want to prove is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  I reduced the coefficients mod 5 and obtained $3x^3+4x+4$, which happens to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ by brute force calculation: none of the 5 elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are zeros, and since the polynomial has degree 3 and no linear factors, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  By the mod $p$ irreduciblity test, I concluded that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Is my proof correct?  Some of the solutions online use the rational roots theorem instead.

Comment: Your proof is ok. I daresay that in this case rational roots theorem is faster than looking for a suitable prime. Particularly, if you work with $f(x/2)$ instead.

Comment: Just because someone uses the rational root theorem does not mean that checking irreducibility modulo a prime is wrong. But next time, if you have to go through every prime until you happen to find that $37$ works, that time could've been better spent. That said, for fourth degree polynomials, the rational root theorem is useless to prove irreducibility while reducing modulo a (small) prime might work.

Comment: Alternatively, let $g=f(x/2)$  and observe that for any integer $n$, $g(n)=n(n-3)-1$ is odd. Hence $g$ has no integer roots, so $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$, and hence over $\mathbb Q$ by Gauss' Lemma.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_5$, observe that $3 \equiv -2$, so that the polynomial is $-2x^3 + 4x + 4$. Divide by $-2$ to get $x^3 - 2x - 2$, which simplifies the brute force calculations. (Equivalently, multiply $3x^3+4x+4$ by $2$ to get the same thing.)

Comment: You can also try Eisenstein criterion, in this case $f(x-1)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein for $p=3$.